# Iterate through ArrayList with If condition and return boolean flag with stream api

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to make myself more comfortable with Java 8 Stream api. 
Currently I want to translate something like as stream, but it seems I am still not comfortable enough, because I have no idea how to do this.

```
boolean isTrue = false;

for (Integer integer : intList) {
    if (integer > 10) {
        isTrue = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you care about is if at least one input from your list is bigger than 10, thus `anyMatch`:

```
boolean isTrue = intList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(x -> x > 10);
```

Comment: can cause NPE ?

Comment: @VdeX I need some context to your question, please

Comment: sorry `intList.stream()` can cause NPE,isnt it?

Comment: @VdeX if the `intList` itself is `null`? of course. I don't get it...

Comment: I mean we should consider using optional. :)

Comment: @VdeX finally :) why not make it clear from the beginning? `Optional.ofNullable(intList).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).anyMatch(x -> x > 10)`

Comment: So sorry, yea I was too abstract :(

Answer (score 3):

- you iterate a List of Integer. So use `Collection.stream()`
- you compare numeric value. So use `Stream.mapToInt()` to work with `int` rather than `Integer` that is more efficient.  Here it doesn't change many things but if you change the stream to do some other numerical operations, you already use the correct way.
- you value a boolean (result) as soon as a condition is met. Otherwise false I assume. So use `Stream.anyMatch(Predicate)`.

So this corresponds :

```
boolean result =
intList.stream()
       .mapToInt(i-> i)
       .anyMatch(i-> i > 10);
```

Comment: Why the `mapToInt()` though to work with a primitive `int` instead of object `Integer`? The `Integer` will get unboxed to `int` anyway at `i -> i > 10` (like in *Eugene*'s answer) without it. And in your answer it still gets auto-unboxed at `i -> i`.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Right.  But suppose you modify the stream later to have other processings , some boxing operations could occur. Using `mapToInt()` here is more a way to write a robust code.

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought about that. I still feel like it's a bit redundant in this case, but I can understand your reasoning behind it now.